# JQPlot pie charts "jqplotDataClick" event fires multiple times

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3, jquery-mobile, jqplot

I am using JQPlot pie charts. I am trying to attach "jqplotDataClick" event to drill down the chart. It works fine, it drill down the clicked chart but i also need to filter the other charts data based on drill down. So I am fetching the data again and rebind the new data to other charts. after binding the data to other charts when i clicked for drill down it fires it multiple times.

I am working with Safari browser

Below is my code
Steps:

1) Create Project in VS 2010 & MVC 3 and JQPlot libraries
2) Add view code in Home/Index.cshtml 
3) Add Controller code in Home/HomeController.cs and run the solution
4) Click on first chart it will show alert where you clicked and drill down and display the filtered data
5) Again click the same chart it will show alert for new and old both data
6) Again click the same chart it will multiply the events for the same charts

**View**

"

```
<p id="p_chartCustomer1" />
```

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var urlGetChartsData = rootPath + 'Home/GetData';
    var filterParam = new Array();
    jQuery.ajaxSettings.traditional = true;
    filterParam.push('1');

    $.ajax(urlGetChartsData,
    {
        data: {
            filter: '', filterParam: filterParam
        },
        success: function (data) {
            if (data.length > 0) {
                var dispdata = [];
                for (var i = 0; i < (data.length); i++) {
                    dispdata.push([data[i].Textt, data[i].val]);
                }
            }                
            LoadData(dispdata, 'p_chartCustomer1', 'chart2');
        }
    });

});

function fetchData(filterParam, chartName) {
    var dispdata = [];
    var urlGetChartsData = rootPath + 'Home/GetData';
    $.ajax(urlGetChartsData,
    {
        data: {
            filter: filterParam
        },
        success: function (data) {
            if (data.length > 0) {
                for (var i = 0; i < (data.length); i++) {
                    dispdata.push([data[i].Textt, data[i].val]);
                }
            }
            LoadData(dispdata, chartName, filterParam);
        }
    });
}

function LoadData(dispdata, chartName, filterText) {

    var plot2 = jQuery.jqplot(chartName, [dispdata],
{
    captureRightClick: true,
    seriesDefaults: {
        // Make this a pie chart.
        renderer: jQuery.jqplot.PieRenderer,
        rendererOptions: {
            // Put data labels on the pie slices.
            // By default, labels show the percentage of the slice.
            showDataLabels: true, diameter: 200
        }
    },
    legend: { show: true, location: 'e' }

});

$('#' + chartName).bind('jqplotDataClick', function (ev, seriesIndex, pointIndex, data) {
    alert('chartName:' + chartName + ' Data - ' + plot2.series[seriesIndex].data[pointIndex]);
    fetchData(plot2.series[seriesIndex].data[pointIndex].toString(), chartName);
    });
}
```

"

**Controller**

```
    public ActionResult GetData(string filter, List<string> filterParam)
    {
        List<TestData> testList = new List<TestData>();
        if (filter.Length > 0)
        {
            testList.Add(new TestData(filter.Split(',')[0], Convert.ToInt32(filter.Split(',')[1])));
            testList.Add(new TestData(filter.Split(',')[0], Convert.ToInt32(filter.Split(',')[1])));
        }
        else
        {
            testList.Add(new TestData("Data1", 20));
            testList.Add(new TestData("Data2", 50));
            testList.Add(new TestData("Data3", 12));
            testList.Add(new TestData("Data4", 20));
            testList.Add(new TestData("Data5", 89));
        }
        return Json(testList, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }

[Serializable]
public class TestData
{
    public TestData(string text, int val)
    {
        this.Textt = text;
        this.val = val;
    }
    public string Textt { get; set; }
    public int val { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: sorry my asp.net view code dosent published

Answer (score 5):

Before adding your bind function, unbind corresponding event :

```
$('#' + chartName).unbind('jqplotDataClick');
$('#' + chartName).bind('jqplotDataClick', function (ev, seriesIndex, pointIndex, data) {
 alert('chartName:' + chartName + ' Data - ' + plot2.series[seriesIndex].data[pointIndex]);
 fetchData(plot2.series[seriesIndex].data[pointIndex].toString(), chartName);
});
```

Comment: You're welcome. Please accept previous post as an answer of your problem for those who will encounter same difficulty.